# Mongodb not exact match query

Tags: mongodb

Hi i want to ask a search query,

Suppose i have list of address: 
“Kebon Jeruk Utama 1”, 
“Kebon Jeruk Barat”, 
“Kebon Jeruk III”

and then i search “Kebon Jeruk Utama” with mongo, all of the list should appears in result:

i have done with text search:

```
db.getCollection('blacklist_user').find( { $text: { $search: "Kebon Jeruk Utama" } } )
```

and the result is true, but i want to search on specific field, in this case is `address`, i have tried with regex:

```
db.getCollection('blacklist_user').find( { address: { $regex: "Kebon Jeruk Utama" } } )
```

but the result only 2 of them

Comment: Could you post, how your collection looks like? And your expected output and actual output also?

Comment: The functionality you want can not be done using '$regex' (If you only search "Kebon Jeruk" then it's possible).
Using $text will search all text indexed fields. If you want only the field address to be searched with $text, you have to remove other field from text index.